# Run OnChange event for each row in table - MVC

Tags: javascript, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

MVC 5 - Razor, Javascript
Novice user!!

I would like to be able to run a simple onchange event when a checkbox is altered in the table, but the onchange only works for the first row.

I have read that this is because the script only runs on the first row and does not run for the subsequent dynamically populated data.

I understand this but don't know how to fix it... I assume that I need to create an individual ID for each checkbox in the each row - I don't know how to do this.

Also, when the checkboxes have different IDs I don't know how to refer to them to add the onchange.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance.

```
@model IEnumerable<core_point.Models.RegisterEmployee_Step6Model>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Select the roles that you have been employed to do, by clicking the check-box...</h2>

<table class="table">


    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr class="h3">
            <td class="vert-align">
                <img src="@item.IconLocation" height="80" width="80" />
            </td>

            <td class="vert-align">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected, new { @id = "CheckBoxSelected" })
            </td>

            <td class="vert-align">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleDescription)

            </td>

            <td class="vert-align">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Role, new { hidden = "hidden"} )
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
<div>
    Roles selected:<input type="number" id="noSelected" value="0"/>
</div>

<script>

    var fld_CheckBoxSelected = document.getElementById("CheckBoxSelected");
    var fld_noSelected = document.getElementById("noSelected");

    fld_CheckBoxSelected.onchange = function () {

        if (fld_CheckBoxSelected == true) {

            fld_noSelected = fld_noSelected.value + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            fld_noSelected = fld_noSelected.value - 1;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace id with class in CheckBoxFor:

```
<td class="vert-align">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected, new {@class= "CheckBoxSelected"})
</td>
```

In Javascript code use fallowing code:

```
(function($) {
    var onChanged = function(){
        /*Do smth that you needed*/
    };  
    $(function() {
        $(".checkbox").on("change", onChanged)
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because all your input boxes will have the same Id value "CheckBoxSelected". That is invalid markup.**Id values should be unique.**

You may consider removing the id from the markup and use a css class.

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsSelected, new { @class = "mycheckBox" })
```

and using jQuery library, listen to the `change` event on the input element with this css class.

```
$(function(){

   $("input.mycheckBox").change(function(){
      var isSelected = this.checked;
      alert("Checkbox changed");



      if (isSelected ) {
        $("#noSelected").val( parseInt($("#noSelected").val())+ 1));
      }
      else
      {
        $("#noSelected").val( parseInt($("#noSelected").val()) -  1));
      }
   });

});
```

Assuming the current value of input with id `noSelected` is a numeric value(else `parseInt` will fail).